# can not filter json api

Tags: javascript, json, api

i am trying to filter this json API, using regex...  i receive some json,  when i input some letter for example "j" in input field, i want to return author of quote for instance "jessie", and it works perfectly, but i have problem, if i want to return error alert, if in this json APi there are  not author names for  letter "f"  , what i can to do, i tried everything but can't figure out what happens to me :(

```
//my HTML looks like this:

 <div class="container mt-5" ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 m-auto">
                    <h3 class="text-center mb-3" style="color: rgb(10, 10, 10); font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;">
                        Search Characters Quotes by their names
                    </h3>
                    <div class="form-grup">
                        <input type="text" class="imput form-control form-control-lg"   title="Only Alphabets" id="search" placeholder="search">
                    </div>
                    <div id="match-list"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

//my javascript looks same

const search = document.getElementById("search");
const ResultHtml = document.getElementById("match-list");



 const request = async () => {
                const response = await fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/quotes");
                const data = await response.json();
                renderYourData(data, search.value);

     }

     const renderYourData = (data, searchtext) => {
        const x= data.filter(film=>{
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchtext}`, 'gi');
            return film.author.match(regex)});


            function retquote(){
                ResultHtml.innerHTML =`<div class="some">${x.map(function(bra){
                    return `<p>${bra.author}</p>`
                }).join("") } </div>`
            }
             retquote();
    }


     window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                request();          
     });

search.addEventListener('input',request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your retquote function to check if array length exist, if yes display the results otherwise put a default error message

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/utnqeLmf/

```
 function retquote() {
        if (x.length) {
          ResultHtml.innerHTML = `<div class="some">${x.map(function(bra){
                        return `<p>${bra.author}</p>`
                    }).join("") } </div>`
        } else {
          ResultHtml.innerHTML = 'no records found'
        }
      }
```